# How to write this query using Laravel 5 Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to write this `Sql` query using in *Laravel 5 Query Builder*.

```
SELECT  * FROM Call WHERE phone_number NOT IN (SELECT phone_number FROM Phone_book)
```

or(Alternative way)

```
SELECT * FROM   Call
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone_Book
          ON (Call.phone_number = Phone_book.phone_number)
```

or(Alternative way)

```
   SELECT * FROM   Call
        WHERE  NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT * FROM   Phone_book
             WHERE  Phone_book.phone_number = Call.phone_number)
               WHERE Phone_book.phone_number IS NULL
```

I tried several ways but i couldn't write a query.is there any way to use `Sql` syntax with in query builder  or how write this same query using **Query Builder**? please , help me.

(I tested above 3 query out put is same . I want to write these one query using **Query Builder** syntax)

Comment: Which query (not "quarry") do you actually want to build using Laravel?  Have you tested any of these queries?

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen  I edited question.

Comment: These queries are NOT the same.

Comment: Attempted code using query builder?

Comment: @aldrin27 I attempted [http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins] .but i couldn't take expected results. :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen of course sir   , i think only about output. can you do any help for me. i tried till yesterday morning. :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::table('Call')->whereNotIn('phone_number', function($query)
{
    $query->select('phone_number')
        ->from('Phone_book');
})
->get();
```

This code is absolutely same with the first sql query u posted.